# How sorting parts of array my cause the whole array to be sorted

Tags: arrays, sorting

Recently i come across this problem and i couldn't find a solution for it, the problem is there is a array of numbers (N number) and we want to sort them, but we sort them in the way that shows in the picture:

[image]

```
First Sort from 1 to K+L  
then Sort from K+1 to N  
then Sort from 1 to K+L again.
```

that means from K+1 to K+L will sort twice.
The question is what is L should be to whole array be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `L = N - K`, the whole array could be sorted.

Comment: Because `K+L = N` in this case, and after the last step (sort from 1 to K+L) the whole array must be sorted.

Comment: Surely I'm not kidding. You asked "what is L should be to whole array be sorted", which means `L` is an arbitrary number that could be assigned by you, and you need to come up with a good `L` to make the "whole array be sorted" condition hold.

Comment: but L is always equals to N - K! is there something i can't see? I'm really confused now!

Comment: In your figure `L` doesn't looks like equal to `N-K`.

Comment: But I'm still suspicious because if L = N - K in fact we sort that array twice and that seams pointless, don't you think there is a way to sort parts of array separately and come up with a full sorted array?

Comment: @MasihAkbari Are you looking for "quick sort' or "merge sort"?

Comment: it really doesn't matter witch sort method.